# Android - creating a view with with a list adapter and additional fields doesn't render anything

Tags: android, android-layout

I am playing around with this sort of a view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/solution_title"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Label1"
    />  

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/solution_description"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Label2"
    />  

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="20px" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

What I want to do is use a ListAdopter to display the ListView and show a list of items, and use simple text labels for the first two items.

Right now I get nothing rendering when I try to just display the first two text fields:

```
public class SuggestedSolutionActivity extends ListActivity 
{
    ArrayAdapter<SolutionTopic> adapter;        

    ArrayList<SolutionTopic> problems = new ArrayList <SolutionTopic>( );   

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<SolutionTopic>(this, R.layout.solution, R.id.label, problems);

        final TextView solution_title  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.solution_title);        
        final TextView solution_description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.solution_description);

}
```

Any idea why the TextView fields don't render for me?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you figured out the problem yet?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Load your layout
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<SolutionTopic>(this, R.layout.solution, R.id.label, problems);

    final TextView solution_title  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.solution_title);        
    final TextView solution_description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.solution_description);

     // Bind to our new adapter.
     setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

In the layout, you should change the id of the ListView:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="20px" >
</ListView>
```

I'm almost sure it will work :)

PD: Why are you using final for the obtained TextViews? If you don't want to change the properties or content of the TextViews, you don't even have to get them with findViewByID, they will just be rendered with the setContentView(R.layout.your_layout). And if you want to change them (maybe adding a Listener), I think you can't use "final", but I'm not fully sure about that.

Comment: got this error: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.problemio/com.problemio.SuggestedSolutionActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list' .....and I did change the xml file to be id list.

Comment: Change ListView id from android:id="@+id/list" to android:id="@android:id/list".

Comment: It also barfs on this line: setContentView(R.layout.solution);

Comment: 03-20 02:29:14.822: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at com.problemio.SuggestedSolutionActivity.onCreate(SuggestedSolutionActivity.java:46)

Comment: Also this line stopped compiling after I changed the xml to android:list         adapter = new ArrayAdapter<SolutionTopic>(this, R.layout.solution, R.id.list, problems);

Comment: Suppossing your layout is called "solution.xml", then your layout has an error, but the activity code should work. I'm checking the layout.

Comment: Thank you - ps, good point about the final in the TextView fields. I removed that. I just saw it in some example and thought maybe there is some use to it :)

Comment: Notice that your ArrayList is empty, so even if it renders, it will display nothing. You can add some dummy entries to you ArrayList so the ArrayAdapter has something to draw to the ArrayList.

Comment: The line with the adapter has a compile error that says "R.id.list list can not be resolved as a type or field.

Comment: What is your SolutionTopic class? If it's not just a simple String, you should implement a proper toString method for your SolutionTopic elements to be manageable by ArrayAdapter.

Comment: There is a string in there, but there is also an id that I want to preserve, so I made it a class that contains those two elements: the name and the id.

Comment: now it does a runtime exception on this line setContentView(R.layout.solution);

Comment: There's a confusion with that ArrayAdapter declaration. The ArrayAdapter constructor takes a context (in this case, "this"), a layout that will be drawn for each entry in your ArrayAdapter (something simple, maybe just one TextView on it), the id of the TextView in the previous layout, and your array. This example will point you in the good direction: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html

Comment: I seem to have gotten it somewhat right and now it is complaining about a runtime adapter exception

Comment: so should I have two layouts? One for the adapter and another for the other stuff I want to display for that same screen?

Comment: Yes, you´ll have two layout: -a layout for rendering your UI (in your case two TextViews and a ListView). -a layout for rendering EACH of your SolutionTopics (it can be as simple as just a TextView).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you replace the last `TextView` with a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)?

Comment: actually that didn't help. I am trying to do this:         final TextView solution_title  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.solution_title);        and it doesn't render anything to the screen

Comment: It's because it's no longer a text view. In your implementation you must now refer to it as a `ListView`... Since that's what it is.

Comment: that element was still a textview - it was one of the top two. I had not even tried to impelement the list that is supposed to come below the labels.

Comment: ... That's because your ID is wrong, in your question you show the ID for both your textviews to be `view-name`. That is not what you posted above, nor is this issue related to your initial question of how you could implement a list as your last item.

Comment: ah I already fixed the id to match, but it is still not responding well.  :(

Comment: Hmm. You should be able to get it to work without using an adapter, if you're using a listview. Maybe that is causing your issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8984/discussion-between-ikiar-and-geekedout)

Answer (score 1):

```
android:id="@+id/label"
```

change this to

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

When you are customizing a ListActivity, make sure that you always use the listview id as @android:id/list.

Comment: thanks - what does that do? :) I just tried it and it didn't help anything render :(

Comment: Add this setContentView(R.layout.main); I am guessing you are using main.xml. Also do a project clean. You need the "R" file to be regenerated.

Comment: Updated again, messed it up last time

Answer (score 0):

GeekedOut,

There are a number of issues with the code you provided above. Of course, first and foremost (and I know you have fixed) is setting the id to `@android:id/list`. But I did see that nobody explained *why* is has to be that way. `ListActivity` and `TabActivity` require that you use special ids when creating the `ListView` and `TabHost` (etc...) that they will be bound to. This is not so much for the Activity itself as it is for the adapter that it uses. If you don't do this, adapters tend to break (quickly).

Now, as to the rendering. There are either two possibilities: a) its not getting the data; or b) its confused about how to render it. While a) might be a possibility, I'm not seeing that to be the real issue as you are doing *most* things correctly here. The truth is, your use of the adapter is the most likely problem. Here's why:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<SolutionTopic>(this, R.layout.solution, R.id.label, problems);
```

Nowhere in here do you actually tell it to `setContentView()`. You may either set it to a View or a Layout. Given the depth of your layout file, you should set it as the layout with:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.solution);
//We'll stick the adjusted Adapter call here.
```

Now comes the real issue: ArrayAdapter works in a very particular way. You may extend it, but if you don't, you're stuck to *its* way of doing things. The call YOU are using to create an adapter is:

```
new ArrayAdapter<Class>(context, rowItemLayout, textViewId, objects);
```

The key here is the `rowItemLayout` file. The file you provided US is your Activity Layout file. You need a separate XML Layout file for JUST the list item as you want it displayed. In there, you place your `TextView` and give it an id separate from the ones in your Activity Layout file. Right now, your Adapter is freaking out because your referencing a Layout file with a ListView that references a Layout file with a ListView... and they all have the same id in the same space.

A sample rowItem layout would be:

**list_item.xml**

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/mylistitem" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The way you use it will be:

```
new ArrayAdapter<SolutionTopic>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.mylistitem, problems);
```

Now, this eases the confusion for your poor compiler. If you are still having issues rendering your ListView at this point, you may have to consider extending the ArrayAdapter (many do). If you extend the ArrayAdapter, simply make a new class that you can pass the list to. Then override the `getView()` method. Here's a sample:

```
    @Override public View getView(final int position, View convertView, 
    final ViewGroup parent)
    {   final SolutionTopic _app = problems.get(position);

        TextView _text;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

            _text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtAppName);
            convertView.setTag(_text);
        }
        else _text = (TextView) convertView.getTag();

        _text.setText(problems.member);
        return convertView;
    }
```

It's really not too bad from there. There are some other things to consider when extending, but only if you are doing more sophisticated stuffs.

Finally, one tiny morsel of extra help. You should create a TextView in your ActivityLayout file with the id `android:id/empty`. If your list doesn't have data, it will render that box. This will tell you without a doubt whether it is rendering or losing the data.

Hope this helps,

FuzzicalLogic